# using iftoggle to set newtheorem depth

Tags: etoolbox, newtheorem

I am using the same macro file for multiple documents, and I would like their theorems to be numbered differently -- one by section and another by subsection. I'm trying to do this by using iftoggle from etoolbox, as follows.

**macros.sty:**

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{sub}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\iftoggle{sub}{subsection}{section}]
```

**doc1.tex:**

```
\usepackage{macros}
\togglefalse{sub}
\begin{theorem} theorem text \end{theorem}
```

**doc2.tex:**

```
\usepackage{macros}
\toggletrue{sub}
\begin{theorem} theorem text \end{theorem}
```

Unfortunately, this numbers the theorems by section in both documents. My guess is that the toggle must be set before the theorem-environment is defined (although this is not the case with other macros whose definitions involve iftoggle). And indeed, I have found the following non-ideal method for solving this problem.

**macros.sty:**

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\iftoggle{sub}{subsection}{section}]
```

**doc1.tex:**

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{sub}
\togglefalse{sub}
\usepackage{macros}
\begin{theorem} theorem text \end{theorem}
```

**doc2.tex:**

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{sub}
\toggletrue{sub}
\usepackage{macros}
\begin{theorem} theorem text \end{theorem}
```

I find this non-ideal because I would prefer for the entire solution would be contained in the style file, without requiring additional code at the beginning of each new document. Could anyone suggest a robust method for solving this problem?

Comment: Maybe try something like `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} \iftoggle{sub}{\counterwithin{theorem}{subsection}}{\counterwithin{theorem}{section}}`?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see how that addresses the problem. How does it allow me to effectively declare \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] in one document and \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection] in the other document?

Comment: `\counterwithin{theorem}{some counter}` resets the `theorem` counter each time `counter`  changes, and appends its value in front of the `theorem` counter. Isn't it what you want  for ‘counter’ being  either `section` or `subsection`, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Ah, I see now -- I was misreading, thank you for the explanation. However, this doesn't seem to solve the problem as I stated it: it works if I put it at the top of the separate document (after \toggletrue{sub}), but I can't put it in the macros.sty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing optional argument to `\newtheorem` is expanded immediately in order to add the right counter name.

You can defer the definition of theorem-like environments at begin document, when the toggle's value will be known.

#### Skeleton for the `.sty` file

```latex
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,amsthm}

\newtoggle{sub}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\iftoggle{sub}{subsection}{section}]
}
```

#### Example document

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aaron}

\toggletrue{sub}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

#### With `\toggletrue{sub}` commented out

[image]

#### With `\toggletrue{sub}` active

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's great! I figured something like that was going on, and was not aware of the "AtBeginDocument" command. Thank you very much.